# Laravel replace string from database content with an image tag

Tags: php, laravel

Im coding a blog for a website which will have a backend where users can write their own posts.

What I need to do is to enable the author to link in an image into the content, what I need to do is to take a string like `[image="URL HERE"]CAPTION HERE[/image]` and when the website is loading the post it need to identify the string and dissect the url from the caption and tags to output an image + p tag.

I am wondering how i could achieve this in the simplest manner?

I expect the output to be something like:

```
<img src="URL TO IMAGE" alt="CAPTION HERE" /><p>CAPTION HERE</p>
```

Comment: Can you put the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will be handy to what you need:

```php
function parse_images($text)
{
    $find    = array('~\[image="(https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))"\](.*?)\[/image\]~s');
    $replace = array('<img src="$1" alt="" /><p>$2</p>');
    return   preg_replace($find, $replace, $text);
}
```

I tested with the input: `hello [image="http://google.com/a.png"]CAPTION HERE[/image] world!` and got:

```html
<code>hello <img src="http://google.com/a.png" alt=""><p>CAPTION HERE</p> world!</code>
```